# Need help understanding org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream "java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes: 63"

Tags: java, exception, bouncycastle, asn.1, decoder

I am working on a decoder for ASN.1 encrypted file, and getting

`java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes: 63`

I want to understand why bouncy castle is throwing this exception.

If someone can provide me their 2 cent would be much appreciated!

Code Snippet

```
ASN1InputStream bIn = null;
    try {
        byte[] bFile = encoded;
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bFile);
        bIn = new ASN1InputStream(input);

        Object temp = null;
        // logger.info("Decoding and emitting file : ");
        System.out.println("Decoding and emitting file : ");

        while ((temp = bIn.readObject()) != null){
            if (temp instanceof DERTaggedObject) {

                DERTaggedObject octs = (DERTaggedObject) temp;

                ASN1Set instance = ASN1Set.getInstance(octs, false);
```

The Error is being thrown at

```
bIn.readObject()
```

I have tracked the exception to ASN1InputStream class readLength() method.
http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1InputStream.java.html

```
static int readLength(InputStream s, int limit)
  283           throws IOException
  284       {
  285           int length = s.read();
  286           if (length < 0)
  287           {
  288               throw new EOFException("EOF found when length expected");
  289           }
  290   
  291           if (length == 0x80)
  292           {
  293               return -1;      // indefinite-length encoding
  294           }
  295   
  296           if (length > 127)
  297           {
  298               int size = length & 0x7f;
  299   
  300               if (size > 4)
  301               {
  302                   throw new IOException("DER length more than 4 bytes");
  303               }
  304   
  305               length = 0;
  306               for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  307               {
  308                   int next = s.read();
  309   
  310                   if (next < 0)
  311                   {
  312                       throw new EOFException("EOF found reading length");
  313                   }
  314   
  315                   length = (length << 8) + next;
  316               }
  317   
  318               if (length < 0)
  319               {
  320                   throw new IOException("corrupted stream - negative length found");
  321               }
  322   
  323               if (length >= limit)   // after all we must have read at least 1 byte
  324               {
  325                   throw new IOException("corrupted stream - out of bounds length found");
  326               }
  327           }
  328   
  329           return length;
  330       }
```

Any help to help understand why this exception is being thrown is very appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: Either a bug in their code or corrupt input.

Comment: The code looks ok, so I would suspect that the input data is invalid or corrupt.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check if the input data is invalid or corrupted?

Comment: Can you give us some information about where the data comes from, and what the expected format is (i.e. what ASN.1 structure(s) are supposed to be in it). "ASN.1 encrypted file" hints that maybe you're parsing the output from a decryption, in which case an obvious possibility is that it wasn't decrypted correctly. Alternatively, maybe the file is actually base64-encoded or something, and you've skipped a decoding step.

Comment: Thanks for replying! The data I am trying to decode is a PGW-CDR, generated by a Cisco ASR 5000 machine.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are getting this error because you are passing whole stream of your file so at the time of encoding / decoding you need to pass a block / part of byte stream and encode then add to byte array then finally write into a file.

As of your previous post i feel your are encoding a CDRs file, so you should be aware of record length. let me assume you have n number of record of indefinite length and we need to encode it. For example Consider a block of 2048 bytes (you can consider more than avg size of your record) which holds minimum one or more number of record(s).

Add the byte stream of every record into a 2048 byte block, while adding if block is full or having some space but non of the records can store then add filler bytes (i.e. 0xFF  so that you can easily figure it out the number of blocks ) then pass to `ASN1InputStream` to get `DERTaggedObject` then encode the stream and store it in separate variable and after encoding everything just write stored stream into a .dat or any file system.

You can refer [this link](http://www.bitpapers.com/2012/04/bouncy-castle-asn1-api.html) for better understanding od encode / decoding process

Answer (score 0):

By the "ITU-T Recommendation **X.690**" also known as "**ISO/IEC 8825-1**" BER Length can be encoded in two forms:

- *definite form* as implemented in your source.
- *indefinite form* - not covered this source.

### Definite form

If Value length <128 (i.e hexadecimal `0x00` to `0x7F`) it is encoded in *short form* - in one byte.

For length more than 127 it is encoded in *long form*. The length octets shall consist of an *initial octet* and one or more *subsequent octets*.
In this case:

- bit 8 in first Byte (*initial octet*) should be one. (source code line 296)
- bits 7 to 1 in Byte 1 shall encode the number of *subsequent octets*(Bytes) in the length octets, i.e. followed after this byte. (source code line 298 get the size)
- the value 11111111 (0xFF) shall not be used for *initial octet* - This restriction is introduced for possible future extension.

In the original **ASN.1** I see no limitations for long form *subsequent octets* size, but other specifications can apply own rules for it.

For sample **ISO 7816** can use lengths **up to 5 bytes** (including initial octet/byte). In other words *initial octet* value could be `0x81`, `0x82`, `0x83` or `0x84`.

You can exclude or change the size checking at lines 300 to 303 if you want to cover other length sizes. In this case additional implementation for Value size resolution will be required due to `int` length number limitation. Changing length to `long` type allows to use up to 8 *subsequent octets*(Bytes).

But probably your input data and it's length is not feet ASN.1 BER/DER TLV encoding rules.

Comment: You are incorrect. DER do not support indefinite length, only definite form is supported.

Comment: Don't exclude the lines at 300 to 303. It's there for a reason. You will not be able to initialize a byte array for content (VALUE) of asn.1 node if the LENGTH octet is more than 4 bytes long. Look what is the limit of int in java. In c# sizeof(int) is 4 bytes.

Comment: In addition to @pepo, bit 8 of the first length byte (after length identifier) must be set to zero, otherwise, length calculation will result in negative number (because `int` is signed, while length must be non-negative).

Comment: Thanks guys for noticing about numeric limitations. For sure, in case real requirement to support BER length more than 5 bytes the value size resolution should be re-implemented. I can't imagine the reason to use TLV data with more than 4 294 967 296 bytes...

Comment: I looked up int limit in java is also 4 bytes. This may be a stupid question, but why can't we initialize a byte array of asn.1 node with octet length more than 4 bytes long?

Comment: btw, thank you everyone for replying to my post so quick<3.

Comment: @user3499505  Java arrays are indexed using an int.  This limits how large they can be.